# Typescript generic factory function including parameters for created object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a factory class in Typescript. The factory should be set up to create a specific class of object, including default parameters set up at factory initialization.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```js
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any) => T;

class Factory<T> {
    private params: ConstructorParameters<Constructor<T>>;
    private ctor: Constructor<T>;
    init<TCtor extends Constructor<T>>(tConstructor: TCtor,
        ...params: ConstructorParameters<TCtor>)
    {
        this.ctor = tConstructor;
        this.params = params;
    }

    create(): T {
        return new this.ctor(...this.params);
    }
}

class ClassWithParams { constructor(a: number) { } }

const factory = new Factory<ClassWithParams>();
//factory.init(ClassWithParams);
// Compilation error - missing param a

factory.init(ClassWithParams, 1);
console.log(factory.create());
// instance of ClassWithParams
```

The above code works well ([Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Constructor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20new(...args%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Factory%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20params%3A%20ConstructorParameters%3CConstructor%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20ctor%3A%20Constructor%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20init%3CTCtor%20extends%20Constructor%3CT%3E%3E(tConstructor%3A%20TCtor%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...params%3A%20ConstructorParameters%3CTCtor%3E)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.ctor%20%3D%20tConstructor%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.params%20%3D%20params%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20create()%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this.ctor(...this.params)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ClassWithParams%20%7B%20constructor(a%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20factory%20%3D%20new%20Factory%3CClassWithParams%3E()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2Ffactory.init(ClassWithParams)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Compilation%20error%20-%20missing%20param%20a%0D%0A%0D%0Afactory.init(ClassWithParams%2C%201)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(factory.create())%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20instance%20of%20ClassWithParams%0D%0A%0D%0A)). However, it requires an `init()` call for the factory directly after construction. I can't move the `init()` code into the constructor because `init()` relies on a generic parameter `TCtor` in order to properly typecheck the parameter list.

I could make `TCtor` a generic parameter of the class instead, but that would mean every time Factory is referenced generically an additional type parameter would need to be supplied for no reason.

Any ideas to remove that `init()` call?

Comment: I realized my answer had a mistake in it that caused type information to be lost. Please see the updated version

Comment: Oh interesting, it seemed to work for me - what type information was lost?

Comment: The return type of `Factory.prototype.create` was wrong. Try the new version

Comment: @AluanHaddad the new implementation is incorrect - there is no type error for incorrect parameters.

Did you mean `tConstructor: C` instead of `tConstructor: Constructor<T>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with the following code

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class Factory<T, C extends Constructor<T> = Constructor<T>> {
    params: ConstructorParameters<C>;
    ctor: Constructor<T>;
    constructor(tConstructor: Constructor<T>,
        ...params: ConstructorParameters<C>) {
        this.ctor = tConstructor;
        this.params = params;
    }

    create(): T {
        return new (this.ctor)(...this.params)
    }
}
class ClassWithParams { constructor(a: number) { this.a = a; } a: number } 

const factory1 = new Factory(ClassWithParams);

const factory2 = new Factory(ClassWithParams, '1');

const factory3 = new Factory(ClassWithParams, 0);


const value = new Factory(ClassWithParams, 0).create().a;
```

As seen in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Constructor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Factory%3CT%2C%20C%20extends%20Constructor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Constructor%3CT%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20ConstructorParameters%3CC%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ctor%3A%20Constructor%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(tConstructor%3A%20Constructor%3CT%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...params%3A%20ConstructorParameters%3CC%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.ctor%20%3D%20tConstructor%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.params%20%3D%20params%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20create()%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20(this.ctor)(...this.params)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20ClassWithParams%20%7B%20constructor(a%3A%20number)%20%7B%20this.a%20%3D%20a%3B%20%7D%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20factory1%20%3D%20new%20Factory(ClassWithParams)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20factory2%20%3D%20new%20Factory(ClassWithParams%2C%20'1')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20factory3%20%3D%20new%20Factory(ClassWithParams%2C%200)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20value%20%3D%20new%20Factory(ClassWithParams%2C%200).create().a%3B) it's convenient and correct.